# How do I login in a User in Rails Using Test Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In rails I have a before_filter that checks and requires that the user is an admin for certain actions in the controller.

However, I need to write tests for these controllers.

So, I have something that looks like this:

```
test "should get create" do
    assert_difference('Event.count') do
      post :create, FactoryGirl.build(:event)
    end
    assert_not_nil assigns(:event)
    assert_response :success
  end
```

user_factory.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :admin do
   email 'aa@example.com'
   password 'password'
   password_confirmation 'password'
   admin true
  end
end
```

But need to login as an admin to be able to create the event. Any ideas on how to do this? The admin column is just a true/false column in the users table.

Edit: First Attempt:

```
 test "should get create" do
    admin = Factory(:admin)
    login_as(admin)
    assert_difference('Event.count') do
      post :create, FactoryGirl.build(:event)
    end
    assert_not_nil assigns(:event)
    assert_response :success
  end
```

generates error:

```
 1) Error:
test_should_get_create(EventsControllerTest):
NameError: uninitialized constant Admin
```

**Update:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
   email 'aa@example.com'
   password 'password'
   password_confirmation 'password'
  end
end
```

and

```
test "should get create" do
    login_as(FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true))
    assert_difference('Event.count') do
      post :create, FactoryGirl.build(:event)
    end
    assert_not_nil assigns(:event)
    assert_response :success
  end
```

and I get the error `test_should_get_create(EventsControllerTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method 'login_as' for #<EventsControllerTest:0x007fb4faec1b28>`

Comment: Your factory is trying to create an Admin constant. Does that exist in your factories.rb?

Comment: @Trip, I've add my user_factory.rb. I'm not sure what you're asking, but I have an admin column in my users table, and it is a Boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define your `factory(:admin)`, FactoryGirl looks for a class called `Admin`, which is why you're getting that error.

You don't need to create a separate factory for `admin`; you can simply use your User factory, passing in `admin: true` (that'll override the default factory settings). So do `admin = Factory(:user, admin: true)`. Make sure you have the `user` factory defined of course.

If you want to keep the `:admin` factory, you need to specify that the class is `User`. The syntax goes something like this:`factory(:admin, class: "User")`.

Comment: You've definitely got me headed in the right direction, but I think I'm still missing something. Can you confirm that login_as is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I haven't used that method, but it should work if you use `session[:user]` to keep track of your current user. Here's the one-line source for login_as: http://recker.rubyforge.org/classes/AuthenticatedTestHelper.src/M000019.html You can always write your own login method in `test_helper` instead. What error are you getting?

Comment: Just saw your edit. Not really familiar with Test::Unit, but check that you have the necessary includes (`test_helper`, others perhaps). Also, you can always write your own `login` function (just copy the `login_as` code and put it in `test_helper`).

Comment: the line I ended up using was: `sign_in(FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true))`, but you need to include `include Devise::TestHelpers`. It was already included in test_helper.rb in my case.